# Page orientation doesn't work in OpenOffice with Python

Tags: python, openoffice.org

I am trying to set the pageorientation in an OpenOffice document with python. The following code i use to try this:

```
import json
from win32com.client import Dispatch as Dispatch
svm = Dispatch("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
svm._FlagAsMethod("Bridge_GetStruct")
coreflect = svm.createInstance("com.sun.star.reflection.CoreReflection")
desktop = svm.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
doc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/swriter", "_blank",0, [])
txt = doc.getText()
cur = txt.createTextCursor()
```

Then i tried two different approaches:

```
p = doc.getPagePrintSettings()
p[8].Value = True
doc.setPagePrintSettings(p)
```

and

```
oStyleFamilies = doc.getStyleFamilies()
oObj1 = oStyleFamilies.getByName("PageStyles")
oObj2 = oObj1.getByName("Default")
oObj2.IsLandscape = True
```

Both give no error, but the page is still in Portrait.. Anybody has an idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you are using Python with openoffice, why not use it's bindings instead of doing it via win32com?

Comment: Well i have more scripts in combination with this. This is just an extra thing I need in a specific document.

Answer (score 0):

try : oObj2.setPropertyValue("IsLandscape",True)
see http://codesnippets.services.openoffice.org/Calc/Calc.SwitchOrientation.snip